# bs4.BeautifulSoup() returning <class 'list'>?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to scrape a website.

I'm having a problem with the `bs4.BeautifulSoup`:

```
for i in range(len(links)):
    linksRes = requests.get(links[i])                                           
    linksRes.raise_for_status()                                                 
    linksSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(linksRes.text, 'lxml')                        
    for e in linksSoup.find_all(href=re.compile(r'/especial/example')):
                                otroProducto.append(e.get('href'))              

for i in range(len(otroProducto)):
    detalleRes = requests.get('http://www.example.com' + otroProducto[i])
    detalleRes.raise_for_status()
    detalleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(detalleRes.text, 'lxml')
```

The thing is, the first `bs4.BeautifulSoup` returns a `"class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'"` as I expected, but the second one returns an empty `"list"` type.

I guess it has something to do with the string concatenation I'm doing there, but I just can't figure out how to make it a BeautifulSoup type to be able to extract some info I need.

Comment: Wait, why do you expect `requests.get` to return a `bs4` object?

Comment: Im sorry, i meant bs4.BeautifulSoup returning <class 'list'>?
Edited!

Comment: Do you have an example of what `otroProducto[i]` might look like? So you can check if the string concatenation for the url might be correct?

Comment: well, `detalleRes` returns <Response [200]>

Comment: and `otroProducto` is a list with this structure: ['/especial/example', '/especial/example', '/especial/example']

Comment: ok, i had created an empty list variable... that was the problem, im sorry i didnt post the whole code, it has to do with my job....